# squid how to exclude an IP address from tcp_outgoing_address

Tags: squid

My squid server has one fixed IP address and a few dynamic IP addresses that may change. I want to use the dynamic IP addresses as tcp_outgoing_address, excluding the fixed IP address from being used as tcp_outgoing_address. How do I set it up? I would prefer not to change the  conf file when the dynamic IP addresses change.